# Is there a logger function from php or should this be written using exec?

Tags: php, linux

On linux in shell programming I use to being able to use the logger command to write the system log. Is there the equivalent function to do this from PHP? Or is it common practice to use exec("logger...") to do this?

Comment: You want to write to the system log from PHP? Why don't you use a dedicated log?

Comment: This is to put a unique message in the system log.

Comment: Which system log? error log?

Comment: /var/logs/messages, that system log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to fill a system log with errors when you break code - been there, done that. :)

However you can either make your own logging system, or maybe have a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.syslog.php